# How to make the content slide smoothly together with the sidebar?[react]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, transition

When my sidebar transitions to width: 0, the content right next to it (on its right) doesn't slide with it. It's like the text waits for the sidebar to be done with its animation before it takes the sidebar's place, even though I set its transition as well.

I came up with a minimal reproducible example below:

```
//Sidebar.js
import './styles/Sidebar.css'

export const Sidebar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
  const toggle = ()=>{
    setShow(!show);
}

  return (
    <div>
        <div id={'toggle-btn'}>
            <button type='button' className='toggle-btn' onClick={toggle}>
                toggle
            </button>
        </div>
        <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
            <aside className={'sidebar' + (show ? ' showSidebar':'')}>
                <ul className='menuList'>
                    <li>Perfil</li>
                    <li>Estatísticas</li>
                    <li>Adicionar Itens</li>
                    <li>Procurar</li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

/*Sidebar.css*/
.sidebar {
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -4px ;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition:all 1s ease;
    height:100vh;
}
.showSidebar {
    width:0;
}

//Dashboard.js
    import './styles/Dashboard.css'
    export const Dashboard = () => {
      return (
        <div className='dashboard'>
        <p>
        LORE IPSUM BLA BLA
        </p>
       </div>
      )
    }

/*Dashboard.css*/
.dashboard {
    max-width: 30%;
    margin-top:10rem;
    transition:all 1s ease;
}

//App.js
function App() {

  return (
    <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
    <Sidebar />
    <Dashboard /> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the `Sidebar`'s `width` from `100%` to `0`, it simply is taken out of the content flow, and `Dashboard` then is reposition to left. To make `Sidebar` and `Dashboard` transition together while one of the two has `width` change, you need to establish a relationship between the two component's widths.

Please refer to this [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-buck-i5zyyq?file=/src/App.js) I put together for you.

In it, I set up a global CSS variable like below:

```css
/* styles.css */

:root {
  --sidebar: 150px;
}
```

And use it in both `Sidebar` and `Dashboard` like below:

```css
/* Sidebar.css */

.sidebar {
  width: var(--sidebar);
  /* no other changes */
}

/* Dashboard.css */

.dashboard {
  width: calc(100% - var(--sidebar));
  /* no other changes */
}
```

With the above, whenever `Sidebar`'s width changes, it'll reflect the value in `Dashboard`'s width, making both transition in sync.

Comment: Thank you! It works for me as well. Hey, why does it need that in that case? I tried to do that with vanilla javascript, and I guess the only difference from the final rendered html was the lack of the .container div that wraps everything, and it worked fine without the need of doing what you did here. Does it have to do with the particular way I structured the html?

Comment: A CSS property transition has little to nothing to do with JavaScript. Was the HTML markup identical between vanillaJS and React versions? Also, regarding the last question, restructuring your HTML markup (and their relevant CSS styles) might in fact help remove the need for CSS variables as shown above.